# Is there a way to create/add files to docker image manually?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to build a ruby-on-rails project, using rails 1.9.3 on Debian image.

After I've built it, using dockerfile, it appears that a directory is missing. So the container doesn't start. So, can I add it manually? I've tried to use "docker run -it  sh" to run it as shell, but for some reason, after I add a directory with mkdir it vanishes, when I exit.

I'm kinda new to this stuff (just did some tutorials), so apologize for any mixed up details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to add the dir, and then commit the changes in the container to make a new image out of it to use the directory in the new image. Its much better to use a repeatable DockerFile to create the image

Documentation for DockerFile -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Have a look at the documentation for commit here -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: Thanks. I'll use commit command, since there is some weird bug that makes ADD/COPY instructions made in the second build file to look files in the wrong directory.